Redis Cache Failed to start at Aspire Startup application
Good day,
I've been following the next tutorial to implement Redis to my apps but first of all I must understand how implement redis well to my apps.
Link to the tutorial
Then when I run my app (running docker desktop) the app shows me this:

And when clicking my webfrontent url, it takes a while to load and cache is not working.

I followed the tutorial step by step.
I used the "docker pull redis" to get the image.

Nothing worked and seems to be no more information on web.

Are there any logs?
